# Calculating the area covered by isochrones in QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, isochrone

I created isochrones using Iso-Area algorithm as polygons in QGIS. Is there any tool in QGIS that helps with calculating areas covered by created polygons?

Comment: E.g. `$area` with field calculator?

Comment: I have polygons of four time intervals. The attribute table of created polygons has only an id field and a cost level which shows the time intervals. I think it is not possible to calculate are using $area or area functions of field calculator.

Comment: Why not? `$area` calculates the area based on the geometry, not based on attributes.

Comment: @Babel Thanks for your help. There are 16 rows in the attribute table with the IDs from 0 to 4. I guess each id is related to one polygon. So to calculate the area of each polygon I need to sum up the areas that are related to the same id, right? one more question, are areas in square centimeters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use field calculator: `$area` or `area ($geometry)` calculates the area for each feature. If you want to get the sum for each group with the same `id`, use the aggregate function `sum` like: `sum ($area, group_by:="id")`.

The unit of measurements depends on the layer's CRS, have a look in the layer properties. For the difference between `$area` and `area($geometry)` see the help here: https://qgis.org/api/2.14/qgsexpression__texts_8cpp_source.html

`$area`:

> Returns the area of the current feature. The area calculated by this
> function respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting
> and area unit settings. For example, if an ellipsoid has been set for
> the project then the calculated area will be ellipsoidal, and if no
> ellipsoid is set then the calculated area will be planimetric.

`area ($geometry)`:

> Calculations are always planimetric in the Spatial Reference System
> (SRS) of this geometry, and the units of the returned area will match
> the units for the SRS.